# In insomia, error 404 Cannot POST /register

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

url: http://localhost:4006\register

- yes im using 4006 port on env
- yes in insomia, it is set to POST
- in router, POST was also used

**routes->auth.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const upload = require("../utils/multer");
const {registerUser} = require('../controllers/authController');
router.post('/register', upload.single("avatar"), registerUser);
module.exports = router;
```

**insomia**

```
{
"name": "torta",
    "email": "torta@gmail.com",
"password": "password",
"avatar": {
    "public_id": "cld-sample-5",
    "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dntwvebaj/image/upload/v1696485294/cld-sample-    5.jpg"
          },
"role": "user",
"createdAt": "11/8/2023"
}
```

**Result was** : Cannot POST /register
error 404 code